# Terminal over file browser in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

The Terminal only covers the editor part of VSCode and not the file browser as well. Is there a setting to tell VSCode that you want the terminal to be the full width of the screen, even when the file browser is visible?

Also, any idea what the keyboard shortcut is to hide the terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're asking whether one can increase the width of the integrated terminal so that it overlaps the sidebar(in your case you're referring to a file explorer), then the answer is a no to my knowledge. If you're asking about maximizing /reverting the terminal, then that's a [work in progress](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/47661). It has not been merged yet!

But you can toggle(hide) the sidebar to get the full width of the terminal, which can be done very neatly with the <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd> (cmd for mac) keybind for toggling sidebars.

You can toggle the terminal using <kbd>Ctrl+`</kbd> (it's the backtick key over TAB).

Hope this helps you somehow.

Comment: Yeah, I would like it to overlap with the sidebar. On small monitors, the terminal is pretty small when the sidebar is visible, which means to actually see the terminal you have to hit two keys, not one. The sidebar for me is always open because it puts the code (with 80 char width) center in the screen which is better, but when I want to use the terminal, the more width the better.

Comment: Oh, and as for ctrl+` toggling the terminal, it doesn't toggle, it just opens. As far as I can tell, there is no way to close the terminal with a key combo. I would love for ctrl+` to actually toggle, meaning I can use it to both open and close the terminal. Right now, I have to use the mouse to close the terminal which is a pain.

Comment: i am able to toggle using ctrl+`. Maybe there must have been some remapping in your vscode config. Just check out the official docs https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_terminal-keybindings

Comment: After updating using ctrl+` seems to toggle fine now.

Answer (score 7):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70050400/836330 for an updated answer as this is now out of the experimental stage.

---

This is a feature that is behind an experimental "flag" in the Insiders Build v1.63.

`Workbench > Experimental > Panel: Alignment`

Setting that to `left` will cover the bottom of the Side Bar if the Side Bar is on the left.  If you have the Side Bar on the right side, then `right` would cover that.

`justify` appears to be the most generic option and will cover the Side Bar **and the Side Panel** whether one or both are open and on the left or right or both sides.

[image: get the terminal under the Explorer demo]