# VS Code: Is there a way to customize layout? (Not using the preset toggles)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know VS Code offers to toggle the explorer and panel into a second position, but none offer the desired layout in the image below. Is there a way I can do this by snapping them or even an extension or way to edit the layout code?

This would be useful as I like to use split terminals and some things like server code and especially SQL tables looks nicer when it doesn't wrap.

[image: Default VS Code layout]

[image: Desired VS Code layout]

Comment: your 2 images are identical.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54277536/terminal-over-file-browser-in-vscode