# Is there a way to make the terminal in VSCode take up the entire width of the application even if the sidebar is open?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to make terminal span the entire width of the application without closing the sidenav? I use it quite a bit, and often I have to hide the sidenav in order to see it in full width. It would be great if I could set it up so the sidenav is just alongside the editor, allowing terminal to take up the full width of the application.

[image]

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This is in Stable v1.64 now.

Go to `View/Appearance/Align Panel/Justify` or use the Layout Control icon on the upper right mentioned below.

Other options for the Panel alignment are `center/left/right`.

[image: Panel alignment options and Layout Control]

---

Note that that the Layout icon on the upper right was recently added  with this setting:

`Workbench > Layout Control: Enabled`

---

Also, as of v1.75 this can be done via the context menu for the Panel.  Right-click on an open space of the Panel to the right of the View headers to open the context menu:

[image: Panel align options in Panel context menu]

See [Release Notes: Manage Panel Alignment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_75.md#manage-panel-alignment-from-panel)

Comment: great thanks @Mark. I was looking for it for years :-D

Answer (score 8):

It's already available since version **1.64**.
Let's switch to Justify option.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

<s>**Unfortunately, it is not possible at the moment.</s>

<s>There is a ticket for this feature in the VSCode repository - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/42149</s>

#### UPDATE:

It's already available since version 1.64.
See other answers below for more information