# Is it possible to have the integrated terminal of VScode below the activity and side bars?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to have the integrated terminal of VSCode below the activity bar and side bar (Explorer...) and if yes, how ?

Comment: Do you mean like this: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70050400/836330

Answer (score 1):

A close solution: You could move the Terminal to a panel within the Side Bar by dragging the Terminal tab to the bottom of an open Side Bar panel:

[image: screencast]

<sup>VSCode 1.45.1 on macOS Catalina</sup>

Comment: Interesting. I meant having the terminal taking all the width of the window.