# Terminal is on top of vscode explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

how to leave the terminal occupying only the width of the editor and not being on top of the explorer?

The following screenshots are demonstrating what I mean, the first one being what is installed on my machine via SNAP, and the second one I got from the official github github page.

[Terminal is on top of vscode explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Z5xr.jpg)

[Terminal in the official page vscode (github)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BemF4.jpg)

In search of an answer I found this solution that was in experimental form at the time, however, I found in the settings of 'Workbench > Panel: Default Location', the options of:
Left, bottom, right.

Because it is experimental, this solution has been removed from the 1.63 update or is in some other location that can still be swapped for the user to choose whether or not to overlay explorer.

[Terminal over file browser in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54277536/terminal-over-file-browser-in-vscode)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70050400/836330 - you want the `center` option.  It must be on `justify` somehow.

Comment: Thanks man, you are correct. I've been researching this for a long time, but only today that I opened this question here. But I didn't realize that the inverse path would be the answer, in the case of looking for when I wanted to have the terminal covering the entire width of the editor.